# Trying to execute a BiqQuery stored procedure from a Google Cloud function

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run this SQL within BIGQUERY ML

```
BEGIN
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `recommendation_engine_ds.purchase_recommender`
OPTIONS(model_type='matrix_factorization',
        user_col='customer_id',
        item_col='item_id',
        rating_col='rating',
        feedback_type='implicit'
        )
AS
SELECT customer_id, item_id, rating 
FROM `unique-moon-366800.recommendation_engine_ds.quality_matrix`;
END
```

and I am getting

> Query error: Training Matrix Factorization models is not available for on-demand usage. To train, please set up a reservation (flex or regular) based on instructions in BigQuery public do

I created a procedure to setup slots and create the reservation

```
BEGIN
CREATE CAPACITY `unique-moon-366800.region-us-central1.my-commitment` 
AS JSON """{
 "slot_count": 100,
 "plan": "FLEX"
}""";
CREATE RESERVATION `unique-moon-366800.region-us-central1.my-reservation`
AS JSON """{
 "slot_capacity": 100
}""";
CREATE ASSIGNMENT `unique-moon-366800.region-us-central1.my-reservation.my-assignment`
AS JSON """{
 "assignee": "projects/unique-moon-366800",
 "job_type": "QUERY"
}""";
END
```

but the error still occurs even if I run the procedure to setup the slots and reservation before tying to create the model.

Comment: *Matrix factorization is only available to flat-rate customers or customers with reservations . On-demand customers are encouraged to use flex slots to use matrix factorization.*  see more here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Comment: Turns out that all that was wrong was that I did not wait for the reservation to setup, that seems to take 30s. All was good after I waited 30s and then ran the matrix factorization.

Answer (score 0):

could you please email bqml-feedback@google.com. The team will help you over there.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback will contact them. Thx.